# Disabling Django CSRF for views that do not always have a response

Tags: python, django, csrf, decorator, django-csrf

I have a Django view that receives POSTs which do not need to have the CSRF token. Therefore I used the `@csrf_exempt` decorator on the view. The problem is that sometimes I do not issue a response from the view (it's a Twitter bot, it receives an HTTP POST for every tweet and I do not want to respond to every tweet). When I don't issue a response I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "/home/adam/webapps/newman/lib/python2.5/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in get_response
   response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

 File "/home/adam/webapps/newman/lib/python2.5/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 24, in wrapped_view
   resp.csrf_exempt = True

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'csrf_exempt'
```

resp (which I assume is the response) is None because the view was exited with just `return`.
How can I avoid this error and still not require CSRF tokens in the POST.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Django really expects view functions to return responses.  Maybe you could return an empty response instead of None?  Or return an HTTP error code?

Answer (score 9):

I know you already got your answer, and indeed Ned's right;
but in addition to that: not only Django really expects views to return a response, your client also! It's an HTTP error and likely a resource waste not to return something (and thus close the connection straight away)!

I would think that a 204 No Content or 304 Not modified (see: [HTTP Status Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)) are the appropriate http codes to use in this situation; in [django](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects):

```
return HttpResponse(status=204)
```

or

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotModified
return HttpResponseNotModified()
```